# Coordinates in delimited text interpreted as attributes instead of as point geometry

Tags: qgis, csv

Delimited text fields with coordinates, although present in the attribute table, are not displayed on the map. And in general, only displayed as data in the file. See pictures.

[image]

Can you tell me where the error is?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E0U2wLPtfQ7C5HLt6naqAFciC2-ccYOE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I would change the decimal separator in the CSV from comma into point and try again.

Comment: then it looks like that 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eJpBzC9bzDNX2e291qHwgDnlLVngl1oR/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please post at least a small snippet of your data.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UjJJq7IIFrxvtQSQz7VYs7mcn-KLGUrb/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please add the things you try and the resulting screenshots to your question body, it makes it much easier for the reader to have all the information in one place.

Comment: This doesn't look like the same file as your above screen shot. The CSV file easily creates points with attributes using either X and Y as Longitude and Latitude, or EAST and NORTH as EPSG:32633.

Answer (score 2):

Delimited text can use commas as decimal separators but there is a check box to indicate that is how numeric fields should be interpreted. In the delimited text dialogue, open the "Record and Field Options". Place a check mark by "Decimal separator is comma".

[image]

With that option checked, the longitude and latitude columns are properly interpreted as numeric and loaded as point geometries for the layer. Without that option, the field is misinterpreted and results in NULL values being loaded into the attribute table. As shown below, the coordinate fields are NULL and the layer shows as only tabular data in the layers list.

[image]